# android intent across 3 activities

Tags: android-intent

### A intent problem

Here's my problem: assume that I got 3 Activities A,B and C.

Fist i'm in A,call startActivity*ForResult*(..) to jump to B.
But i wish when B is returned , C will be launched rather than A.

Can it be possible and how do i do to make it?

Actually,int A,i call startActivity*ForResult*() to launch Camera Activity to take a photo ,and return the data to C.

Thank you for answers!

```
A extends Activity{
   startActivity();//jump to B
}
B extends Activity{
   takePhoto();//this is a camera program of android system for taking photos
}
C extends Activity{
   getIntent();//i wish photo data would delivered here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u could do like this:

```
A extends Activity{
  startActivity();//jump to C
}
B extends Activity{
  takePhoto();//this is a camera program of android system for taking photos
}
C extends Activity{
  onCreate() {
    startActivity(); // jump to B
  }
  startactivityforresult() {
    getIntent();//i wish photo data would delivered here.
  }
}
```